# Solving an ODE given the initial conditions.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm pretty new to ODEs. I have an ODE with $x_{h}$ being the equilibrium happiness state such that it can at times be great than or less than $0$.

My ODE is as follows:
$\frac{dx}{dt} = -r(x - x_{h})$

$x$ is the emotion of a person, could be happy or sad. Now, if someone X is very happy it implies that $x>x_{h}$ and after some time, X state will return to equilibrium.

$r$ is the fractional rate at which $x$ returns to normal

I am now trying to solve that ODE with the `initial conditions` $x(t_{0}) = x_{0}$ and this is where I get stuck

Here is how I solved the ODE:

`Separating the variables`

$\frac{dx}{dt} = -r(x-x_{h})$

$\frac{dx}{x-x_{h}} = -rdt$

`Integrating on both sides and I get the result:`

$x = Ke^{-rt} + x_{h}$

Now, this is where I get stuck. Given my `initial conditions` $x(t_{0}) = x_{0}$, how do I replace it in my solution to get the final form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've found
$$
x(t) = Ke^{-rt} + x_{h}
$$
so for $t=t_0$ you have
$$
x(t_0) = Ke^{-rt_0} + x_{h}=x_0
$$
and then you can find the constant $K$
$$
K=(x_0-x_h)e^{rt_0}
$$
so that
$$
x(t)= x_{h}+(x_0-x_h)e^{-r(t-t_0)}
$$

Comment: why downvote???

Comment: Welcome to the club of the victims of anonymous and unjustified downvotes !

Comment: Ah the foolish downvoters. Thanks for the answer :) Quick question regarding the solution. What can we say about it? In terms of happiness as described?

Comment: At $t_0$ you have the level of happiness $x_0$. For $t\gg t_0$ (ideally for $t\to\infty$) the level of happiness will approach the equilibrium $x_h$. Putting $y(t)=x(t)-x_h$ that is the level of happiness with respect to the equilibrium or the "excess of happiness", we have $y(t)=y(t_0)\mathrm e^{-r(t-t_0)}$; we see that this will be lower than the initial level at $t_0$ and it is maximum (or minimum if negative) for $t=t_0$.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Plugging in $t_0$ in your solution, you get $$x_0=Ke^{-rt_0}+x_h \implies K=e^{rt_0}(x_0-x_h)$$ Therefore the final solution will be $$x(t)=e^{r(t_0-t)}(x_0-x_h)+x_h$$